# How do I create a ReadableStream in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, web-standards

Both [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/ReadableStream#Browser_compatibility), [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=streams), and Microsoft Edge's own ["Platform Status"](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/streamsapireadablestream/?q=readablestream) page state that Microsoft Edge supports `ReadableStream` since build number 16299+ (released 09/26/2017).

However, when I try to create a ReadableStream in the latest Edge (Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763) I get the error `Function expected`.

Both

```
new ReadableStream()
```

and

```
new ReadableStream({
  start: function(controller) {},
  pull: function(controller) {},
  cancel: function() {}
})
```

throw the `Function expected` error. Omitting the `new` also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it working in another browser?

Comment: Works in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the following code to read the data in Edge:

```
function pump(reader, context) {
    return reader.read().then(function (result) {
        if (result.done) {
            console.log('ReadableStreamReader: complete! Received ' + context.receivedLength);
        } else {
            var chunk = result.value;
            console.log('ReadableStreamReader: Partial chunk, chunkSize = ' + chunk.byteLength);

            context.receivedLength += chunk.byteLength;
            return pump(reader, context);
        }
    }).catch(function (e) {
        throw e;
    });
}

function fetchVideo() {
    var url = 'xxxxxxxx';

    var headers = new Headers();
    var param = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default'
    };

    var context = {
        receivedLength: 0
    };

    fetch(url, param).then(function (res) {
        console.log('Content-Length: ' + res.headers.get('Content-Length'));
        return pump(res.body.getReader(), context);
    }).catch(function (e) {
        throw e;
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't allow me to create a ReadableStream that I'm in control of – so it's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ReadableSream doc example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream), I reproduce the issue on my Edge 44, but it works well on Edge 42. So, I suppose the issue is related to Edge 44, as a workaround I suggest you could try to downgrade the Edge version to 42 version. And, I will try to feedback this issue to Edge Platform.